# What happens when I finish the last totem?

Tags: king-of-thieves

In single player I can see there are a limited number of bases for me to move to and after each totem expires I have to move to continue doing rituals. What happens when the totem in the last house breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a random dungeon being regenerated, as in a rebuilt totem with 8 teeth, and you will be able to move into that dungeon again. The dungeon layout that they give you is completely random, so you might get a completely different dungeon from the one that was there already. I haven't reached the last totem yet, so I don't know if you need to re-buy traps when you move in. All other dungeons you see in single-player remain the same. When you break the totem you just got, another one will generate at a different location with full teeth, so you'll need to scroll around a lot if you move frequently. This happens indefinitely, so you'll never run out of totems.

Source: This youtube video -